# It is possible to draw a $4$ sides polygon with these side dimensions?

Tags: geometry

It is possible to draw a $4$ sides polygon with these side dimensions:

$$30 \times 29.8 \times 21.8 \times 31.4$$

How can I test the validity of these dimensions?

[image]

Comment: "How can I test the validity of these dimensions?" without more information, you can't.

Comment: More interesting - based on your diagram - would be to ask if it is possible to  draw a trapezoid with these side lengths. The answer here is yes, but the decision process is more involved than for a simple quadrilateral.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the longest side is shorter than the sum of the other three: Yes, you can.

Here, we clearly have $31.4<30+29.8+21.8$, so it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is an infinity of quadrilaterals with these dimensions.

Pick a value for the length of a diagonal (not exceeding the sum of the adjacent sides), and build two triangles with the imposed sides.